# warning:mysql_connect()[function.mysql-connect]: [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am using wamp 2.1. While running my application, I'm getting following error continuously :

> warning:mysql_connect()[function.mysql-connect]: [2002] Only one usages of each socket address

Comment: Do not use depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: Maybee you try to connect twice?

Comment: I have used mysql_* in my all project but it's giving problem to my one of it only... Actually its located on server and more than 30 users accessing it from client isde

Answer (score 0):

change Listen 80 to Listen "some other number ex: 88" in Apache httpd.conf file.  or quit other programs which using port 80 . Culprit may be skype

Comment: which one parameter should i change...is it "ServerName localhost:80" to "ServerName localhost:88" or "#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 80" to "#Listen 12.34.56.78:88 Listen 88"

Comment: search Listen 80 and replace with Listen 88, and restart, try in browser localhost:88

Comment: I tried your solution....now it's showing loading for few seconds, when only one user is logged in..instead it should show pages quickly..

Comment: When I delete some data it works ok...but as entry get inserted and data becomes little bit heavy...it arising same problem...

Comment: @VijayaSavant - Simply changing ports wouldn't affect page load times.